# Invalid Response From /.well-known/acme-challenge while implementing SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have a windows machine on which Nginx is used to serve node-red. I have two node-red servers set up running on different ports.
I have mapped two domains for the same IP. On one domain certbot SSL is configured and is working fine.
For the second domain, Certbot is showing an error. I have added the below lines in Nginx as well -

```
location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what is missing.

Comment: First this is probably off topic for Stack Overflow, should probably be asked on SuperUser. Second without knowing what the error is and more details about how you've set up nginx this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a dedicated folder for ACME - and make sure it has the proper file permissions:

```
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root c:\documents and settings\myUser\html_folder\acme_challenges\;
    }
```